# R: How to Align Date

Tags: r

I use `getSymbols()` from package `quantmod` to get stock data:, and convert it to weekly as below:

```
 SSEC=get(getSymbols("000001.SS",from="2015-02-01",to="2015-03-01"))
 to.weekly(SSEC)


            SSEC.Open SSEC.High SSEC.Low SSEC.Close SSEC.Volume SSEC.Adjusted
 2015-02-06   3128.30   3204.91  3075.91    3075.91           0       3075.91
 2015-02-13   3095.12   3203.83  3095.12    3203.83           0       3203.83
 2015-02-17   3222.36   3246.91  3222.36    3246.91           0       3246.91
 2015-02-27   3228.84   3310.30  3228.84    3310.30           0       3310.30
```

But I found the date of the 3rd row of above is `2015-02-17`(Tuesday), which is not what I suppose to be the end of the week `2015-02-20`(Friday). Could anyone teach me how to align the date of above to every Friday?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Please supply the code you used to get the data.

Comment: Using the `xts` function `to.weekly()` (included in `quantmod`) provides the correct dates. On February 16th the US markets were closed due to a holiday; this could have led to the mistake in the code that you used to create the data.

Comment: Thanks to RHertel's explanation. Such mistake is really due to a holiday. I added the code to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you Friday of that week for any supplied date:

```
x = c("2015-02-06","2015-02-13","2015-02-17")
x = as.Date(x,format="%Y-%m-%d")

print(x)

today_week = as.numeric(strftime(x, format = "%U"))
today_year = as.numeric(strftime(x, format = "%Y"))
today_comb = paste(today_year,today_week,0,sep="-")

friday_week = as.Date(strptime(today_comb,format="%Y-%W-%w")) + 5
print(friday_week)

[1] "2015-02-06" "2015-02-13" "2015-02-17"
[1] "2015-02-06" "2015-02-13" "2015-02-20"
```